Compilation errors while building Envoy 1.31.0 from sources
I am trying to build Envoy 1.31.0 from sources and i am stuck while compilation with the following error :
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/fc9d07c8fa1ae7ff490efa6f3e8eaa23/external/com_google_cel_cpp/runtime/standard/BUILD:23:11: Compiling runtime/standard/comparison_functions.cc failed: (Exit 1): clang-14 failed: error executing command (from target @com_google_cel_cpp//runtime/standard:comparison_functions) /usr/bin/clang-14 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wthread-safety -Wself-assign -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fcolor-diagnostics -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++14' ... (remaining 34 arguments skipped)


/include/c++/12/type_traits:1364:23: error: incomplete type 'cel::JsonObject' used in type trait expression
                    __bool_constant<__has_trivial_destructor(_Tp)>>

Clang and LLVM version - 14
bazel build command :
bazel build --config=clang envoy --cxxopt=-std=c++20 --host_cxxopt=-std=c++20

Tried if it works with c++17 or c++14 compilers, both of them did not work :(
Any ideas on how to fix this up..?

Good on you for filing this as an issue but I don't think anyone will be able to reproduce this exact issue because it appears to be linked to your system specifically.
